# Display data in an HTML table using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JSON response like the following.

```
"result": [
    [1, 0.10, 1.00],
    [2, 0.20, 2.00],
    [3, 0.30, 3.00],
    [4, 0.40, 4.00],
    [5, 0.50, 5.00],
    [6, 0.60, 6.00],
    [7, 0.70, 7.00],
    [8, 0.80, 8.00],
    [9, 0.90, 9.00],
    [10, 1.00, 10.00],
    [11, 1.10, 11.00],
    [12, 1.20, 12.00],
    [13, 1.30, 13.00],
    [14, 1.40, 14.00],
    [15, 1.50, 15.00],
    [16, 1.60, 16.00],
    [17, 1.70, 17.00],
    [18, 1.80, 18.00]
]
```

This corresponds to a `java.util.List<Object[]>` in Java.

---

The response is received by the following JavaScript/jQuery function.

```
var timeout;
var request;

$(function () {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#zoneCharge").change(function(){
        if(!request)
        {
            request = $.ajax({
                datatype:"json",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'getZoneCharges', id:'jsonrpc', params:[$("#zoneCharge").val()]}),
                contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
                url: "ZoneChargeList",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    var list=response.result;
                    var tempWeight='';
                    $('#dataTable').remove();
                    var $table = $("<table id='dataTable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>").appendTo($('#zoneChargeList'));

                    $('<tr>').appendTo($table)
                    //.append($("<th style='width: 96px;'>").text("Weight"))
                    //.append($("<th style='width: 96px;'>").text("Charge"))
                    .append($("<th style='width: 96px;'>").text("Weight"))
                    .append($("<th style='width: 96px;'>").text("Charge"));

                    $.each(list, function(index, list) {
                        list[2]===null||list[2]===undefined||list[2]===''||isNaN(list[2])?tempWeight='':tempWeight=list[2].toFixed(2);
                        $('<tr>').appendTo($table)
                        .append($('<td>').text(list[1]))
                        .append($("<td><input type='text' name='txtCharge[]' value='"+tempWeight+"' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event, this.value);'>"));

                    });
                },
                complete: function()
                {
                    timeout = request = null;
                },
                error: function(request, status, error)
                {
                    if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                    {
                        alert(status+" : "+error);
                    }
                }
            });
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                if(request)
                {
                    request.abort();
                    alert("The request has been timed out.");
                }
            }, 30000);
        }
    });
});

<span id="zoneChargeList"></span>
```

I want to display this list of data in `<table>` in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxyMX.png) format.

[image]

---

The `$.each` function in the success handler currently displays this list in `<table>` in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4UXw.png) format.

[image]

How to show this list in a table of **four columns** as shown by an equivalent snap shot above?

<sub>The jQuery function is invoked when an item is selected from `<select>` whose `id` is `zoneCharge`</sub>

Comment: Honestly, you could probably save yourself a lot of bother with something along the lines of https://datatables.net

Comment: not related, but... `datatype` -> `dataType`

Comment: I have changed it to `dataType`, @KevinB. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (and here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/83d4w/5/) :

```
var newTr = null;
var resetTr = true;
$.each(list, function(index, list) {
    list[2]===null||list[2]===undefined||list[2]===''||isNaN(list[2])?tempWeight='':tempWeight=list[2].toFixed(2);
    if (!newTr) {
        // create new row
        newTr = $('<tr>');
        // do not reset it this time
        resetTr = false;
    } else {
        // we used the previous one so reset it this time
        resetTr = true;
    }
    newTr.appendTo($table)
        .append($('<td>').text(list[1]))
        .append($("<td><input type='text' name='txtCharge[]' value='"+tempWeight+"' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event, this.value);'>"));

    if (resetTr) {
        // reset
        newTr = null;
    }
});
```

- `newTr` contains the current `tr` being used or is null.
- `resetTr` will decide if we reset `newTr` at the end of the loop.

**[edit]** Oh and of course you can uncomment the two heading cells

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to replace your `$.each` call with an actual `for` loop, and then inside your loop, create the `td` tags for `index` and `index+1`.  Then the `for` loop should increment the index by 2 instead of by 1.  That way, your loop is basically adding a row for every other index, and putting two indices per row.