# HTML Table template header

Tags: html, css, templates, html-table

I have several HTML tables that using the same header row.

```
<tr>
  <th width = "70%">Heading 1</th>
  <th width = "12%">Heading 2</th>
  <th width = "9%"><img src='/images/img1.png' height=25 width=25></th>
  <th width = "9%"><img src='/images/img2.png' height=25 width=25></th>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to create re-usable template for a header that can be user across multiple table? Like creating a class and assigning it to

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use `classes` to do that and pass the values in HTML via `JS`, `Angular` or what ever you want

```css
.table-box{
  width: 100%;
}
.table-box tr th:nth-child(1){
  width: 70%;
}
.table-box tr th:nth-child(2){
  width: 12%;
}
.table-box tr th:nth-child(3),
.table-box tr th:nth-child(4){
  width: 9%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-box">
  <tr>
    <th >Heading 1</th>
    <th >Heading 2</th>
    <th ><img src='/images/img1.png' height=25 width=25></th>
    <th ><img src='/images/img2.png' height=25 width=25></th>
</tr>  
  
</table>
```

Comment: Can I add values in class? i.e. Heading1, img src

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you means by value? If you were talking about data then  tell me which language you were using as back-end

Comment: No data. I am using Javascript and I am ok on that part. I have 4 tables that have identical header but different data. I am hoping to find a way to style and fill column names just ones and re-use it 4 time as template, instead to copy and paste 4 times.

Comment: You dont need to copy and paste just get data from your Array list using loop and call that inside 'th'

Comment: I think you were talking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863848/display-data-in-an-html-table-using-javascript-jquery

Comment: I am sorry I am not making myself clear. I don't have any problems with getting and posting data into tables. What I would like to "simplify" is initial table creation via html. As of now, I have 4 tables in which I re-use the code for a header row. I am hoping to stream-line that similar to what you suggested with class="table-box" but with ability to assign column titles in a single place.

Comment: Sorry @goryef i didn't get your point but may be this is what you were talking about [header for dynamic table in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46620183/add-table-header-for-dynamic-table-in-javascript) OR the best way is to update question and tags with the latest code what you have tried so far so that we can understand it clearly and help you